# How to create a textfile with the names of a directory of images?

Tags: vba, vbscript, directory, text-files

Hallo my name is Dennis and I have the following directory `IMAGES\`:

```
EX0010040324303-001.tif
EX0010040324303-002.tif
EX0010040324303-003.tif
EX0020943843934-001.tif
EX0020943843934-002.tif
EX0030673452099-001.tif
EX0030673452099-002.tif
```

What do I want?

A loop through the directory and
to compile a textfile as follows:

```
EX0010040324303,,IMAGES\EX0010040324303-001.tif,Y,,,3
EX0010040324303,,IMAGES\EX0010040324303-002.tif,,,,
EX0010040324303,,IMAGES\EX0010040324303-003.tif,,,,
EX0020943843934,,IMAGES\EX0020943843934-001.tif,Y,,,2
EX0020943843934,,IMAGES\EX0020943843934-001.tif,,,,
EX0030673452099,,IMAGES\EX0030673452099-001.tif,Y,,,2
EX0030673452099,,IMAGES\EX0030673452099-002.tif,,,,
```

So:
DocId2,,DocId,Y,,,NumberOfPages     for the first tif-page of a doc and
DocId2,,DocId,,,,                   for the other tif-ages of a doc

At the moment, I have produced the following script:

```
Function readCompleteText(inputReadLocation, OutputwriteLocation)
Const ForReading = 1
Dim lenInputReadLocation
Dim docId
    Dim docId2
Dim oStream
Dim translationFileContents
Dim inputText
lenInputReadLocation = LEN(inputReadLocation)

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set FileList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='"& inputReadLocation &"'} Where " _
                & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")

For Each objFile In FileList
    Dim i
    i = 0
    docId = RIGHT(objFile.Name,(LEN(objFile.Name)-lenInputReadLocation-1))
    docId2 = LEFT(docId, LEN(docId)-4)
    MyArray = Split(docId2, "-")

    EXnumber = MyArray(0)
    PageNumber = MyArray(1)

    'inputText = EXnumber &",,"& docId &",,,,"
Next

oStream.WriteText inputText,0
oStream.SaveToFile OutputwriteLocation      
oStream.close
oStream = Nothing
End Function
```

My questions are:

- how can I count the number of pages per document?
- how can I write the textfile with the file-names of the images as shown above.

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Do the TIF files contain multiple pages or is each file a single page? Judging by the naming scheme, they could be one page each, with "_001" as the first page, "_002" as the second and so on.  Also, what specifically are the fields that you want to output to the text file? I see what looks like a segment of the file name a blank field that isn't even used, a partial file path, a mysterious "Y"... could you provide more details so the question can be answered?

Comment: Hello Steve P, thanks for your reaction. Yes, it are single page tif-files, with 001 as the first page of the doc, 002 as the second and so on. I hace edited the question above as well.
So yes, I need as output a segment of the file name, then two comma's, then the folderpath, a comma, a "Y" if it is the first page , three comma's, the number of pages if it is the first page.
Hope it is more clear now! Would be really great if this could be solved! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you extract the information of the file, put those information in a collection of (TifFile) objects that you store in a dictionary by their Id:

(unfortunately I could not test the code, but you'll get the idea)

```
class TifFile
    Public FileName
    Public DocId
    Public DocId2
    Public ExNumber
    Public PageNumber
End Class

'[..snip..]

Set TifFileCollection = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each objFile In FileList
    ' Do some parsing here
    docId = RIGHT(objFile.Name,(LEN(objFile.Name)-lenInputReadLocation-1))
    docId2 = LEFT(docId, LEN(docId)-4)
    exNumber = Split(docId2, "-")(0)
    pageNumber = Split(docId2, "-")(1)

    ' Put it in an object
    Set oTifFile = new TifFile
    oTifFile.FileName = objFile.Name
    oTifFile.DocId = docId
    oTifFile.DocId2 = docId2
    oTifFile.ExNumber = exNumber
    oTifFile.PageNumber = pageNumber

    ' Add the file to a collection
    if not TifFileCollection(DocId).Exists then
        Set TifFileCollection.Item(DocId) = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    end if
    TifFileCollection.Item(DocId).Add oTifFile
Next

' Iterate through all files
prefix = "IMAGES\"
distinctNumberOfFiles = TifFileCollection.Count
For each id in TifFileCollection.Keys
    Set collectionOfTifFilesWithSameId = TifFileCollection(id)
    numberOfFilesWithSameId = collectionOfTifFilesWithSameId.Count

    for each oTifFile in collectionOfTifFilesWithSameId.ToArray()
         If (numberOfFilesWithSameId > 1) and (oTifFile.PageNumber = "001") then
             multipage = "Y"
             pageCount = numberOfFilesWithSameId
         else
             multipage = "N"
             pageCount = ""
         End if
         ' Output:
         MsgBox join(array( _
             oTifFile.DocId, _
             "", _
             prefix & oTifFile.FileName, _
             multipage, _
             "", "", _
             pageCount), ",")
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. To keep things clear, I have opened a new thread, trying to simplify your code. Yyours gave an error so I though trying to cut out as much as possible would be a good way to debug - however I am not successfull. Could you have a look here? I am using a similar example to keep it clear for you (once done, I think I should be capable to translate it to my own specific situation). Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689660/howto-create-a-multi-dimensional-array-from-images-in-a-directory