# Howto create a multi-dimensional array from images in a directory?

Tags: vba

Consider the following directory of tifs:

```
EX0008-001.tif
EX0091-001.tif
EX0091-002.tif
EX0091-003.tif
EX0777-001.tif
EX0777-002.tif
```

I need to write a VBA script that compiles a specifically formatted input file. Each TIF image is constructed as `DOCUMENT-PAGE`, so `EX0008-001.tif` is a TIF image for page 1 of document `EX0008`. In order to compile the input file, I first need to put images into a multi-dimensional array, as follows:

```
Array(
  [EX0008] = Array (001)
  [EX0091] = Array (001, 002, 003)
  [EX0777] = Array (001, 002) 
)
```

For this, I have to use VBA. The problem is I only have an understanding of php. I have been searching a clear guide on how to solve my problem in VBA but was unsuccesfull. Example code from @AutomatedChaos was too advanced for me.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
currentDirectory = objShell.CurrentDirectory 

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(currentDirectory) 

Set TifCollection = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 

For each objFile in objFolder.Files 
    If objFso.GetExtensionName (objFile.Path) = "tif" Then 
        fileNumber = Split(objFile.Name, "-")(0) 
        pageNumber = Split(objFile.Name, "-")(1) 

    If Not TifCollection(fileNumber).Exists Then 
        Set TifCollection.Item(fileNumber) =  CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 
    End If 

    TifCollection.Item(fileNumber).Add pageNumber 
    End If 
Next
```

Since this is also my first introduction into VBA, I would like to keep my code as simple and consise as possible. Could you help me getting the above code to work? I don't understand the error message I get (`Class doesn't support Automation: TifCollection`) since I defined `TifCollection` as an array, not a Class?

Comment: "System.Collections.ArrayList" is VB.NET  Your example array doesn't match any structure available in VBA: maybe you're looking for something more like a Dictionary object (which you can find in the `Scripting.Runtime` library) ?

Comment: `System.Collections.ArrayList` is only available through VBScript, if you use VBA, use the Dictionary as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use .Net classes in VBA, unless they expose a COM interface, hence the error you're seeing.

VBA does support arrays directly, but they're just integer-indexed arrays.  You'll need to use the [Scripting.Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object.  The following is not tested, but should be close to what you're after.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
currentDirectory = objShell.CurrentDirectory 

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(currentDirectory) 

Set TifCollection = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 

For each objFile in objFolder.Files 
    If objFso.GetExtensionName (objFile.Path) = "tif" Then 
        fileNumber = Split(objFile.Name, "-")(0) 
        pageNumber = Split(objFile.Name, "-")(1) 

        If Not TifCollection.Exists(fileNumber) Then 
            TifCollection.Add fileNumber, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
        End If 

        TifCollection.Item(fileNumber).Add pageNumber, ""
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I keep getting the same error as I got previously: `line 14 char 5 Object required "TifCollection(...)"`. I don't understand this error: `TifCollection` is an object created in line 7 already, no?

Comment: @Pr0n0 - `Exists` is a method on the TifCollection object, not the items it stores.  Line 14 should be `If Not TifCollection.Exists(fileNumber) Then`